# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower' error

Tags: python

This is my code please can anyone give me the soultion from the error provided below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/layan/Desktop", line 39, in <module>
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\text.py", line 293, in fit_on_texts
    seq = text_to_word_sequence(
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\text.py", line 74, in text_to_word_sequence
    input_text = input_text.lower()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/layan/Desktop", line 39, in <module>
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\text.py", line 293, in fit_on_texts
    seq = text_to_word_sequence(
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\text.py", line 74, in text_to_word_sequence
    input_text = input_text.lower()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

import re
import nltk

nltk.download(['stopwords','punkt','wordnet','omw-1.4'])
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df= pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\layan\\Downloads\\fake-news-master\\fake-news-master\\train.csv")
df.head()

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['text'],
                                                    df['label'],
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=42)
maxlen=128
truncating='post'
padding= 'post'
oov_tok='<00V>'
vocab_size=1000

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size,
                      char_level = False,
                      oov_token = oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)

training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
training_sequences = pad_sequences(training_sequences,
                                   maxlen = maxlen,
                                   padding = padding,
                                   truncating = truncating)

training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)
training_sequences = pad_sequences(
                                   testing_sequences,
                                   maxlen = maxlen,
                                   padding = padding,
                                   truncating = truncating)
```

Comment: Since the error happens at `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)` we can assume that `x_train` is not a string, so maybe `df['text']` on `train_test_split(df['text'], df['label'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)`

Comment: Seems like `df["text"]` either has float values or nan. Try `df = df.fillna(""); df["text"] = tf["text"].astype(str)`

Comment: could you please specify where should i write it?

Comment: projectpro.io/article/fake-news-detection-project/854 This is the source of the code if you want to check it –

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a value like `2.50` in the .csv file and pandas parses it as a float. Try adding `dtype = str` to make sure everything is parsed as a string.

```py
pd.read_csv('"C:\\Users\\layan\\Downloads\\fake-news-master\\fake-news-master\\train.csv"', dtype = str)
```

Comment: not woriking OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"C:\\Users\\layan\\Downloads\\fake-news-master\\fake-news-master\\train.csv'

Comment: @LayanAlahmadi Forgot a `"`, try now.

Comment: sorry but still not working

Comment: https://www.projectpro.io/article/fake-news-detection-project/854 This is the source of the code if you want to check it